# spring boot 2 + entity/jpa as sub module

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven-3, multi-module

spring boot 2 with maven multi-module project

how can we create JPA/entity as the separate module and add the dependency to the main project ??

I have read many links but still not find the solution, please help...

I want to create a project structure like below...

entity-project - all entity and JPA related configuration [ database and all configuration ]

master-service [ which include entity ] and repository for entity project would be here.

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

This is my project structure below.

**remittance-rs** is the main project module that include all sub module that we define in pom.xml file like this:

```
<groupId>org.soyphea.remittance</groupId>
<artifactId>remittance-rs</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


<modules>
  <module>service</module>
  <module>domain</module>
  <module>remmittant-restapi</module>
</modules>
```

[image]

So I have 3 modules that include **service** is for our logic, **domain** for our DAO and Domain and the last one **restapi** for our exposed rest endpoint.

So all the sub module need to include the parent artifact and group id like below,

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.soyphea.remittance</groupId>
    <artifactId>remittance-rs</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

In your sub module you gonna need dependencies individual for each of them.

**Example**

**domain** module pom.xml will need spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 
let's see detail.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.soyphea.remittance</groupId>
        <artifactId>remittance-rs</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>org.soyphea.domain</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

***This is my sample project in github*** https://github.com/PheaSoy/spring-boot-remittance-project

Comment: thank you for response, but wherever i will use domain module i have to set database configuration right ??

Comment: You can setup configuration with your main module such as web or rest-api module is ok. Because we assume domain module is related on DAO and Entity no configuration at there. Our configure should have one place.

Comment: but I have multiple main project will use entity/dao projects... so how can we configure database configuration in entity/dao module... please help

Comment: could you tell me what are they for your main project? Example: payment-api you should have(domain module for your dao, service module for your logic, and web-mvc or rest-end point for your controller). your configuration should in rest-end point module, I called main module.

Comment: we are using micro services, we have multiple micro services which uses same entities/dao .... thanx for help

Comment: if you want to build the module reusable like this, I would like to recommend you to build the domain as jar file and put in your local repository.

Comment: I have find solution - we need to convert JPA as spring boot to normal spring module and then we can add it